# Adding predictor variables and/ or systematic judgement to time series forecasts

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I have a ways to go with my forecasting general education --- but I'm doing a seasonal time-series forecast for predicting sales order volumes.

It's mostly software sales, which does have a seasonality and clear trends.

I initially have run triple exponential/ Holt-Winters model, which seems to be alright.

Thing is -- I'd like to incorporate sales events in the pipeline (new clients on the horizon, possible future promotions) -- as well as perhaps a way to systematically incorporate a judgement variable -- aka forecasts from the sales director, or other experts.

For example - say we forecast we will do 1000 orders in January. However, sales is talking to a client that has signed on and estimates 200 orders a month. That can probably just be added, perhaps?

But sales is also talking to a client that does 500 orders a month, however, the deal is uncertain. And there are 4-5 of these deals on the horizon. As a rough prediction, would I ask sales a probability of closing the deal? That might be biased or completely made up. Do I assign rough probabilities based on the stage of the deal? Obviously, accuracy will not be high. To be honest, these new deals probably will account for 10% of the forecast in a year. Predicting them will be a bear, but including them would be far more accurate than a model that ignores them.

Also, I've done a lot of reading where a statistical model + judgement outperforms a statistical model or expert judgement by itself.

Is there any systematic way to do this? Even forgetting the judgment forecast for now, how do I add regression variables to a time series? I've vaguely heard of something called an ARMAX, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

Comment: Yes ARMAX is the way to go for adding causal variables. Exponential smoothing does not have the capability to incorporate causal varaibles. If you would like to learn more about forecasting I would recommend 3 books.

Comment: Continuing .... 1. [Forecasting Principles and Practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/)  2. [Forecasting methods and and applications](http://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Applications-Spyros-G-Makridakis/dp/0471532339/ref=la_B002Z79JY4_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1414085629&sr=1-2) (a classic predecessor to the first book, I like this book) 3. [Principles of Business Forecasting](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_17?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=principles%20of%20business%20forecasting&sprefix=principles+of+bus%2Caps%2C148) (very expensive)

Comment: Continuing ... Yes, Judgmental(structured I might add) + Statistical forecast gives better accuracy.